# String concatenation in Perl to a variable

Tags: perl, concatenation

I have a string like this:

```
my $masterP = "A:B:C a:b:c a:c:b A:C:B B:C:A";
my (@scen) = split (/ /, $$masterP);
foreach my $key (@scen) {
    my ($string1, $string2, $string3) = split (/:/, $key);
    my $new = "${string1}_${string2}";
    my $try .= $try . "$new";
}
print "$try\n";
```

I am expecting $try to print: A_B a_b a_c A_C B_C (with space), but it doesn't work. How can this be fixed?

Comment: Why you expect the spaces? you remove them with the first split. Also you declait $try locally.

Comment: Space in the print statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will do what you require:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $masterP = "A:B:C a:b:c a:c:b A:C:B B:C:A";

my @scen = split ' ', $masterP;
my @try = map { join '_', (split /:/)[0,1] } @scen;
my $try = "@try";
print "$try\n";
```

**Output**

```
A_B a_b a_c A_C B_C
```

Answer (score 0):

Please always use Strict and Warnings to be get valuable code:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $masterP = "A:B:C a:b:c a:c:b A:C:B B:C:A";
my @scen = split(/ /, $masterP); 
my $try;
foreach my $key (@scen) {
    my ($string1, $string2, $string3) = split (/:/, $key);
    my $new = "${string1}_${string2}";
    $try .= " $new";
    $try =~ s/^\s//;    
    chomp($try);
}
print "$try\n";
```